# args.join is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js, args

With my discord bot I am working on a weather command that shows weather on the specified country but when trying to run my command I'm getting this error: `TypeError: args.join is not a function` Any fix?

My code:

```
const weather = require('weather-js');
const discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  name: "weather",
  description: "Get the weather of anywhere",
  category: "info",
  usage: "weather <>",
  run: ( message, args, client) => {
    
 weather.find({search: args.join(" "), degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
try {
 
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Weather - ${result[0].location.name}`)
.setColor("#ff2050")
.setDescription("Temperature units can may be differ some time")
.addField("Temperature", `${result[0].current.temperature} Celcius`, true)
.addField("Sky Text", result[0].current.skytext, true)
.addField("Humidity", result[0].current.humidity, true)
.addField("Wind Speed", result[0].current.windspeed, true)

.addField("Observation Time", result[0].current.observationtime, true)
.addField("Wind Display", result[0].current.winddisplay, true)
.setThumbnail(result[0].current.imageUrl);
   message.channel.send(embed)
} catch(err) {
  return message.channel.send("Unable To Get the data of Given location")
}
});   

    
  }
}
```

I've also tried `if (args[0].join...` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Firstly, is it supposed to have the colon after run? When I tried a colon for an arrow function, it just didn’t work. Secondly, can you please show how you invoke the code?

Comment: Maybe try logging what args is, whatever it is its not a array, maybe missmatched function parameters?
maybe update with how you execute your commands,
also try logging message, do both or either of them and post the results (edit the post)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but you have to split the args `args.split(" ")` before you can join them.

The args returns a string `Hello World!`

If you were to use `args.split(" ")` you could do `const textSplit = args.split(" ")`

It would then return `["Hello", "World!"]` as an **array**

You could **THEN** use `textSplit.join(" ")` to add all strings in the array together with with a space.

It would return a string that says `"Hello World!"`

You could then use `textSplit[0]` to grab specific text from the **array**. The 0 position is the word `Hello`, the 1 position is the word `World!` and so on. Arrays start from the number 0.

[

"Hello", (0)

"World!" (1)

]

*Hope this helps*